# 2005 Mercury Mariner grinding noise, wont start

Tags: starter, mercury, grinding

I have a 2005 mercury mariner that had a hole blown in the engine. We replaced the motor and the starter (the starter kinda broke in half when the hole happened). The vehicle ran for a year and a half but started grinding occassionally when we were starting it. Finally one day it just grinded and wouldn't start. I went and got a new starter, thinking that was it, but it is still not starting and still grinding. I have a video of what it sounds like when trying to start. Please help!

Comment: Done anything like checking oil level?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you have a video a link would be useful, just saying you have one doesn't help much. Did you inspect the flywheel teeth when you replaced the starter?

Comment: I did check oil levels. Everything else is fine. The car was running fine before it started making the grinding noise. And it was occassionally making it during startup before I changed the starter, but would still run basically fine once it started, with no grinding noise during regular operation. It finally just wouldn't start and so I changed the started. It is still making the noise and still wont start.

Comment: The video isn't in a link, just on my phone. I would have to send through fb or text. I am not technologically inclined enough to upload somewhere.

Comment: I am guessing the flywheel teeth are the teeth that the starter is connecting to. I did not. I barely saw them before putting the new starter on because it was a weird angel, I was very stressed out, and I thought the starter was the thing grinding. So, I hoped for a quick fix, and was disappointed. I am extremely ignorant about cars and repairs. I only just learned to change my own oil. But I simply can't afford a mechanic.